# Bootstrap affix always on last tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the bootstrap affix and I have a problem that if the content is not big enough to have a scroll it always shows the last tab as the current. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1he91n2u/).

On the page I'm developing this happens even when there is enough content for scroll, the tab is always pointing to the last element.

Here is my code, I'm sorry for the mess:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollSpy">

    <div class="container-fluid" role="main" style="padding-top: 2em" ng-controller="resultsPageController">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1" id="myScrollSpy">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" data-spy="affix" >
                    <li class="active"><a href="#search">Top</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#results">Results</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#love1">Love 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#love2">Love 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" infinite-scroll="searchService.search()" ng-controller="searchController">
                <div id="search" ng-include="'static/html/search-bar.html'"></div>
                <div id="results">
                    <tabset>
                        <!--<tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" select="setMode($index)" active="tab.active">
                        <div ng-include="tab.include"  ng-if="tab.active"></div>
                        </tab>!-->
                        <tab heading="lala">
                            <ul class="media-list">
                                <li class="media" id="love1">
                                    <span class="title">Love - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</span>
                                    <br />
                                    <span
                                    class="description">Love is a variety of different feelings, states, and attitudes that ranges from
                                        interpersonal affection ("I love my mother") to pleasure ("I loved that meal").</span>
                                    <br />
                                    <span class="url"><img
                                        src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/Wikipedia-favicon.png" alt="favicon" width="16px" />&nbsp;&nbsp;en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love</span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="media" id="love2">
                                    <span class="title">Love - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</span>
                                    <br />
                                    <span
                                    class="description">Love is a variety of different feelings, states, and attitudes that ranges from
                                        interpersonal affection ("I love my mother") to pleasure ("I loved that meal").</span>
                                    <br />
                                    <span class="url"><img
                                        src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/Wikipedia-favicon.png" alt="favicon" width="16px" />&nbsp;&nbsp;en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love</span>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </tab>
                    </tabset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```